# Dollar cost averaging approach to Bitcoin investing?

Tags: exchanges, services, investing

Are there any services offering a [dollar cost averaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollar_cost_averaging) approach to Bitcoin investing, i.e. something like an index tracker fund which purchases a set amount on a regular basis? If not, are there any reasons why such a service can't exist:

- Are there any theoretical disadvantages, i.e. anything specific about the asset which discourages this style of investing?
- Are there technical limitations, e.g. is there some restriction imposed by payment bodies which would prevent making a regular payment from Paypal to Dwolla, from Dwolla to an exchange, then buying coins, in an automated fashion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is also https://www.bitcoinbuilder.com/

This allows an easy setup where you spread your bitcoin buys over a time. Currently only works with mtgox. You create trade-only rights for the bot, so that no high trust for the site is required.

Comment: Seems the site is currently down, don't know if it's still active. Anyway, its announcement thread is https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=67835.0.

Comment: @Jeremias: Welcome! Please try to improve the answer by adding a little bit of info about bitcoinbuilder.com. That way the answer is not totally useless even if the link doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done today.

Dwolla lets you send money to Mt. Gox on a schedule:
 - http://help.dwolla.com/customer/portal/articles/164379-multi-payments-schedule

You then can leave an open market order to buy bitcoins, e.g., a bid for 10,000 BTC.

The moment new funds arrive from Dwolla, Mt. Gox will attempt to execute the remaining part of the order using all USD funds available in the account and those bitcoins will be purchased at the market price at the time.

Of course, this assumed the account is not used for any other trading, as that open bid order would be triggered from any BTC sales that occur.

Comment: The same Dwolla who stole Tradehill's money forging CC chargebacks?